# How to count null values in a summary statistics in python polars?

Tags: python

How do you count null values in a column?
I tried this, but it does not give what I want:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"prod": ['apple','apple','banana','lemon','lemon','lemon'], "price": [11, None, 14, 21, None, 23]})
df.group_by('prod').agg(pl.count().alias('COUNT'),
                        pl.when(pl.col('price').is_null()).then(1).count().alias('NULLS')
                        ).sort(by='prod')
```

Comment: What happens if you try it like this?  
df.group_by('prod').agg(
    pl.count().alias('COUNT'),
    pl.sum(pl.col('price').is_null().cast(pl.int8())).alias('NULLS')
).sort('prod')

Comment: pl.col('price').null_count().alias('NULLS') is a way simpler version of the 2nd agg line

Answer (score 2):

You want count of Null values in Column right?

Then you can use this.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"prod": ['apple','apple','banana','lemon','lemon','lemon'], "price": [11, None, 14, 21, None, 23]})
null_count = df['price'].null_count()
print(null_count) # 2
```

Comment: pl.col('price').null_count().alias('NULLS') is what I was looking for, thx.